# SwiftUI Navigation similar to Slack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a navigation UI similar to the Slack app where I have the Home Screen which Overlays the Menu Navigation screen. I created a ViewModifier which makes the Home Screen Draggable. Now I need to add functionality such that when the "Home" is tapped on the blue Menu screen, the white Home View animates back to the center. My idea was to keep track of the NavigationState in a global AppState:

```
enum NavigationSelection {
  case menu
  case home
}

final class AppState: ObservableObject {
  let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  @Published var currentNavigationSelection: NavigationSelection = .home 
}
```

Then when the user taps "Home", have it update the AppState's currentNavigationSelection, and have the Draggable view determine its offset based on the currentNavigationSelection. I'm really not sure about this approach and I'm having a tough time thinking about it in the new SwiftUI style. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

The view hierarchy looks like this:

```
 var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Menu()
        HomeTabView()
    }
}
```

And the HomeTabView has a draggable ViewModifier applied:

```
struct Slidable: ViewModifier {

  @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState

  @State private var viewState = SlidableViewDragState.normal.defaultPosition
  @State private var currentPosition: SlidableViewDragState = .normal {
    didSet {
        self.viewState = self.currentPosition.defaultPosition
    }
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    return content
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight:
        .infinity, alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
        .offset(self.viewState)
        .animation(.interactiveSpring())
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ (value) in
                self.viewState = self.currentPosition.applyXTranslation(x: value.translation.width)
            })
            .onEnded({ (value) in
                if value.translation.width < 0 && self.currentPosition == .normal {
                    return
                }
                if abs(value.translation.width) > self.currentPosition.switchThreshold {
                    self.currentPosition = self.currentPosition.oppositePosition
                    if self.currentPosition == .menuVisible {
                        self.app.currentNavigationSelection = .menu
                    }
                } else {
                    self.viewState = self.currentPosition.defaultPosition
                }
            })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the technical fun challenge! :) fun for me too! But in general, aren't all UX experts suggesting to not use the hamburger meny solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Moving both views

How do you currently define the positions of both? With my limited experience I would use a `ZStack` embedding `HomeView` and `MenuView`. This way you can move the views around independently.

Then you use a `point` variable as state, and make the `DragGesture` set `point`. Then you determine at the end of the drag what end position `point` is set to.

`point` is part of the offset-calculation. You can calculate the menu-offset with `.offset(x: point.x)` and the home-offset with `.offset(x: -Self.maxOffset - Self.minusHomeWidth / 2 + point.x)`.

`minusHomeWidth` is the width the menu still shows when you are on the home screen.

Variables defining min and max of the `point`:

```
static let minOffset: CGFloat = 0
static let maxOffset: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - Self.minusHomeWidth
static let minusHomeWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 10
```

Then you can make it move to the home-view width

```
Button(action: {
    self.point = CGPoint(x: Self.maxOffset, y: 0)
}) { Text("Go to Home") }
```

Comment: Hey @Fabian I added some more of the code to give context. I think I understand what you're saying and I think that would force me to remove the offset calculation logic outside of the ViewModifier to some object that has context of both views that are being affected, am I right?

Comment: I updated the answer how I would do it, I hope it's a little clearer since I got the chance to try it. It's basically a yes, the offset must be set on both, best modifying it by a single attribute since that is the most simple. You can pass the `point` together with a _closure_ which gets executed at the end of the drag to set where the _point_ should go.